# Performance issue while Querying the oracle database using linked server

Tags: linked-server

I am connecting the oracle db server from sqlserver 2005 using linked server with microsoft oledb oracle drivers.

Table present in the oracle db is having the DateTime Stamp. So i will be fetching only the latest records from that table, by passing the query with where condition.But query is taking 6 to 7 minutes approx.

20 million records are present in the table which i am querying.

Comment: Do the Oracle tables involved have the 'correct' indexes?

Comment: It is out of box and we can't touch the oracle database.

Answer (score 0):

I know this does not answer your question directly, but maybe you could try connecting directly to oracle to grab your data.

In the company I work for, we use a wide range of database backends.  Furthermore, each of which we connect to directly.  There is [LINQ to Oracle](http://www.codeplex.com/LinqToOracle) available in the community.  The method we use in the company I work for is the [Oracle .NET Data Provider](http://www.oracle.com/technology/pub/articles/cook_dotnet.html).

On a side note...  LINQ to LDAP is the one I'm waiting for.  There are ways to write one that compares to the LINQ to Active Directory libraries, but not worth destroying our current model for.